# VBA Option button doesn't work with variable

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder why in my code in VBA option button doesn't work with variable (worksheet), but it works in the same macro when I use `Me.` or call it by full name `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("xxx").` etc.

My code:

```vb
Dim HBC As Worksheet
Set HBC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HBCALC")
For i = 1 To 12
    If HBC.Metric = True Then
        If rng.Cells(1, i) = 0 Then Exit For
    End if
Next i
```

`Metric` is the option button name. When I use `Me.` or `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HBCALC").Metric` it works fine, but when I want to switch it to `HBC.Metric` it returns

> Compile error: Method or data member not found.